# SQL Query to achieve the sequence in the below format

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find solution to achieve the result in the below format using sql.

I have two columns:

```
col1  col2 
 1     e
 1     e
 1     e
 2     e2
 2     e2
 2     e2
 3     e3
 3     e3
 4     e4
 4     e4
 4     e4
 4     e4
 4     e4
 4     e4
 6     e6
 6     e6
 6     e6
```

where col1 has the sequence number and col2 has the events where the col1 has the numbers starting from 1 to 10 ...and so on for each batch of events i.e first batch has the sequence 1, next 2 assigned and so on.

I am trying to renumber the sequence col1 in the format below using sql

```
col1  col2 
 1     e
 2     e
 3     e
 1     e2
 2     e2
 3     e2
 1     e3
 2     e3
 1     e4
 2     e4
 3     e4
 4     e4
 5     e4
 6     e4
 1     e6
 2     e6
 3     e6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col2) col1,
    col2
FROM 
    table_name
ORDER BY 
    col2;
```

Comment: Thanks will give a try

Comment: it works ! but i  am getting additional column for row_number how to get rid of that

Comment: col1 col2
 
    1 1    e

    2 2    e

    3 3    e

    4 1    e2

    5 2    e2

    6  3    e2

    7 1    e3

    8  2    e3

Comment: @gururajjujare Where did you run this query? sql plus? sql navigator? toad?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM YourTable ORDER BY col2, col1
```

> ORDER BY clause helps to get the result in order.

Answer (score 0):

Check Col2 in your procedure use logic Like:

IF col2='e' Then 
Begin
 RESET SEQUENCE 
 SEQUENCE 
end
else IF col2='p' Then 
Begin
 RESET SEQUENCE 
 SEQUENCE 
end

Comment: you can write col2 = 'e' or col2 = 'p'

Comment: `reset sequence` is invalid SQL